# Jquery change function doesn't work with React JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to create input file button in React and I want to show the file name if the file is selected using jQuery.

My component where I call input button component is as follows :

```
<FileInputButton pictureID="idCard" pictureIcon="credit-card" text={language.btnIdCard}
                 btnName="idCard" className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2"/>

<FileInputButton pictureID="statuten" pictureIcon="file-text-o" text={language.btnStatut}
                 btnName="statuten" className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-offset-right-2 col-md-offset-right-2 col-sm-offset-right-2"/>

<div className="clearfix noMarginXs"></div>

<FileInputButton pictureID="blancoBriefhoofd" pictureIcon="file-o" text={language.btnBlanco}
                 btnName="blancoBriefhoofd" className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2"/>

<FileInputButton pictureID="companyPhoto" pictureIcon="camera-retro" text={language.btnCompanyPhoto}
                 btnName="companyPhoto" className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-offset-right-2 col-md-offset-right-2 col-sm-offset-right-2"/>
```

The FileInput component is something like :

```
<div style={{width: '100%', textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 20}}>
            <label className="advanced-button">
                <FontAwesome name="upload" className="faIcon" style={{height: '39px !important'}}/>
                <span className={`btnFileText ${btnName}`}>{text}</span>
                <input id="btnFile" type="file" style={{display: 'none'}} name={btnName}/>
            </label>
        </div>
```

And my jquery code is as follows :

```
    $(function () {
    $("#btnFile").change(function () {
        var id = this.name;
        switch (id) {
            case "idCard":
            {
                filename = $('#btnFile').val().split('\\').pop();
                filenameWithoutExtension = filename.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
                $('.' + id).text(filenameWithoutExtension);
                console.log("Usao je u prvu");
                break;

            }
            case "statuten":
            {
                filename = $('#btnFile').val().split('\\').pop();
                filenameWithoutExtension = filename.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
                $('.' + id).text(filenameWithoutExtension);
                console.log("Usao je u drugu");
                break;
            }
            case "blancoBriefhoofd":
            {
                filename = $('#btnFile').val().split('\\').pop();
                filenameWithoutExtension = filename.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
                $('.' + id).text(filenameWithoutExtension);
                console.log("Usao je u trecu");
                break;
            }
            default: {
                filename = $('#btnFile').val().split('\\').pop();
                filenameWithoutExtension = filename.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
                $('.' + id).text(filenameWithoutExtension);
                console.log("Usao je u default");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

When I click on first button, everything works fine. The text in the span is changed with the selected file, but the other buttons will not work.

**UPDATE**

```
    import React, {propTypes} from 'react';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';

const FileInputButton = ({className, pictureID, pictureIcon, text, btnName}) => {
    return (
        <div className={className}>
            <div className="picture-container" style={{marginLeft: 18}}>
                <div className="picture" id={pictureID}>
                    <FontAwesome name={pictureIcon} size="3x" className="picture-src" style={{paddingTop: 14}}/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style={{width: '100%', textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 20}}>
                <label className="advanced-button">
                    <FontAwesome name="upload" className="faIcon" style={{height: '39px !important'}}/>
                    <span className={`btnFileText ${btnName}`}>{text}</span>
                    <input id="btnFile" type="file" style={{display: 'none'}} name={btnName}/>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

FileInputButton.propTypes = {
    className: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    pictureID: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    pictureIcon: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    text: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    btnName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default FileInputButton;
```

Comment: Don't touch the DOM when you use React, change the model (the data associated with the view) and react will do the rest

Comment: Arnaud is right. Could you add the code of your FileInput component please ?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: This line in the onchange handler looks problematic: filename = $('#btnFile').val().split('\\').pop(); - You've got 4 elements with that id. Which one do you want the value of?  Possibly change that to 'this' so you are getting the value of the changed one? - That said i concur with the other posters that maybe you'd have more success using a pure React approach. I think React supports onchange on input elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this qualifies as an answer but as a sketch a React type approach might be something like:

//in parent component initialise state

function getInitialState: () {
   state = {'displayField' : '', 'displayFieldClass': ''}
   return state;
}

//in parent component define handler

```
function inputChange(e) {
    this.state.displayField = e.target.value;
    this.state.displayFieldClass = 'activeFileName'; //CSS class defined somwhere
}
```

//in parent component display the filename and render the FileInputButton(s) passing in the handler

```
function render() {

    Filename: <span className={this.state.displayFieldClass}>{this.state.displayField}</span>

    <FileInputButton handler={this.inputChange} ...otherProps />

}
```

// in FileInputButton associate the onChange event with the passed in handler

```
function render() {

     <input className="btnFile" type="file" onchange={this.props.handler}>

}
```

Comment: This way is probably better. I will try it. How can I apply some style in inputChange function? I would like to do something like `$('#idCard').css("border-color", "#f0b20e");` . Should I do it also with a state or is there any better way?

Comment: It may seem a bit long-winded but afaik the 'react' way might be to use state again. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Great. Thanks mate. ;)